# calling another function from backbone.js fetch success

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to call another function on success of the fetch in the first function but I keep getting an undefined error.  The console.log('success') is working.

In the view:

```
secondFunction: function() {
  console.log('second function called');
},

someFunction: function() {
  someData.fetch({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log('success');
      this.secondFunction();
    }
  });
 },
```

When I do it like this it's fine but I need the secondFunction to wait until the success of the first for the data.

```
secondFunction: function() {
  console.log('second function called');
},

someFunction: function() {
  someData.fetch({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
  this.secondFunction();
 },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
someFunction: function() {
  var self = this;
  someData.fetch({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log('success');
      self.secondFunction();
    }
  });
 },
```

Note the use of **self**. Keep in mind you are in the callback function ;-)

Comment: self didn't seem to work but var that = this; worked.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you must bind this

`

```
someFunction: function() {
  someData.fetch({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log('success');
      this.secondFunction();
    }.bind(this)
  });
 },
```

`